# Dynamically repeat/tile div and child(s)?

Tags: javascript, css, repeat

I've been doing some searching on here and Google and I can't seem to find an answer that quite fits what I'm trying to do. I have a single div with some text in it that does a fade effect by transitioning to a different background image on mouse hover. What I want to do is to tile/repeat that same div dynamically so it fills the entire body (or parent div). Kind of like using background-repeat:repeat but with a div instead of a background image. I like to see what kind of cool visual effects I can achieve with elements across the entire page fading in and out as the mouse moves over them.

Of course I could just copy and paste the same div in the code a bunch of times but there must be a better solution. I'm thinking javascript is needed, but the only things I've been able to find about cloning divs look to be a bit over my head and I'm wondering if there is a more simple solution.

The CSS and HTML that I'm using as an example is from menu links on a site I'm working on. It may not be the best example but I'm a bit new to CSS. Basically I want to tile the below div across an entire page.

Here is the css:

```
#fadediv {
    background-image:url(images/buttonback.png);
    transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
}

#fadediv:hover {
    background-image:url(images/buttonback2.jpg);
}

.fadedivtext {
    display:block;
    width:320px;
    height:138px;
    float:left;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:138px;
}
```

And the HTML snippet:

```
<div id="fadediv" class="fadedivtext">about me</div>
```

EDIT: Looks like there's a PHP example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761069/how-can-i-make-a-div-that-vertically-repeats?rq=1) that could work, in addition to the javascript example given below.

Answer (score 2):

I think clone should work well for you -- it's not that complicated, especially when you're talking about a basic div.  Just make sure to target classes instead of IDs (you're not supposed to have multiple elements with the same ID).

Here's a basic example using JQuery's [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
var numberOfClones = 20;
var el = $("#fadediv");
for (i=0 ; i<numberOfClones ; i++) {
    var newEl = el.clone();
    $("#container").append(newEl);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9P7bY/2/

---

**Edit**

This is a comment left by [aug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168661/aug):

> Or if you want to for some reason give each clone a unique id you can access the attribute field and change the id to something else

```
newE1.attr("id", newId);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! That looks to be almost exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the example too, I was finding the usage of clone confusing but I think I can work with this.